# Hql Query in Hibernate 6 JPA JDK 11 Apache Netbeans 12 Maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, netbeans

When I do a query(1) as the below:

```
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate");
         em=emf.createEntityManager();
 Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Album");
Long resul=  (long) query.getSingleResult();
System.out.println("Media de precios:" +  resul);
```

Here, my entity is:

```
package Modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author javier
 */
@Entity
@Table (name="album") 
public class Album implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
      @Column(name="numalbum")
    private int id;
    
    
     @Column(name="titulo")
    private String titulo;
     @Column(name="autor")
    private String autor;
    
     @Column(name="precio")
    private int precio;
     

    public Album() {
    }

    public Album(String titulo, String autor) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public Album(int id, String titulo, String autor, int precio) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public int getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 67 * hash + this.id;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.titulo);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.autor);
        hash = 67 * hash + this.precio;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Album other = (Album) obj;
        if (this.id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.precio != other.precio) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.titulo, other.titulo)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.autor, other.autor)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Album{" + "id=" + id + ", titulo=" + titulo + ", autor=" + autor + ", precio=" + precio + '}';
    }
```

The sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `musica` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
USE `musica`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `album`
--

CREATE TABLE `album` (
  `numalbum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `autor` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `album`
--

INSERT INTO `album` (`numalbum`, `titulo`, `autor`, `precio`) VALUES
(8, 'motomami', 'rosalia', 80),
(20, 'bailar', 'sergio', 120);
```

The persistence unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    
   <persistence-unit name="hibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musica"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I execute the code (1), the output of Apache Netbeans 12 gives the following error:

simpleorg.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Album]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser

I don't know to resolve this error, so I have looked in the hibernate 6.0 manual.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried several options and None is valid.
I hope that this program show me the amount of rows of databse.